# Why does sound travel faster while light travels slower in hotter mediums?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, acoustics, refraction

Sound travels at its slowest speed in a vacuum. Once it enters hotter mediums, it travels faster. On the other hand, light travels the fastest in a vacuum. Once it enters other mediums, it travels slower.

**Why is one faster whereas the other slower?**

Similar Questions:

- [Why light travels slower and sound travels faster in denser mediums?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245343/)
  This is my exact question, except the answers are not helpful and only point out the incorrectness of the description without answering the actual answer.

Comment: *Sound travels at its slowest speed in a vacuum.* Are you really sure about this statement???

Comment: @Farcher yes - sound travels at 0 m/s in a vaccuum. You really can't go slower than that.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the answer you’re looking for is that light is a wave without a medium, whereas sound is not. The fact that light can propagate in vacuum at all was not originally obvious, and people thought it must need a medium (the “luminiferous aether”) because, after all, aren’t all waves an oscillation of some “stuff”?

Well, Maxwell’s Equations showed us that an EM wave is self-sustaining: the changing magnetic field begets a changing electric field, which begets a changing magnetic field, which...etc, and this happens in pure vacuum. Sure, light can travel through other stuff too, but other stuff just gets in the way, slows it down.

Sound, on the other hand, really is an oscillation of stuff. It’s not that sound is slow in vacuum, it simply *does not exist*. So stuff is necessary, and if you make that stuff rarer, then the sound wave might slow down, depending on the other mechanical properties.